# Why some Pay Pal Rest APIs are not available for some countries in LIVE transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

When i tried to integrate papal using RestAPIs, The transactions and all working fine with sandbox mode. But in Live payment API fails. When i logged into my paypal account,the 'Direct credit cards' permission is not able to make enable in LIVE. It is shown as msg : "Disclaimer: Unfortunately, due to recent product changes in the region, we are no longer able to allow Live DCC processing via RESTful APIs to Canada. We are continually looking for ways to expand our services, so please stay tuned. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause."

Comment: The country support for REST API direct credit card payments is [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments). You can (still) do `paypal` type payments for Canada. Hth.

Comment: Short answer to "why": compliance with government (and card network) regulations in every country is hard.